# <PropertyGroup> property in SDK

Tags: c#, sdk

recently I got stuck about the SDK.

In my work, I need to detect any projects have  `<CheckForDuplicateItems>` set to false, but I didn't find any details in the website about this `<PropertyGroup> property`.

Does the label has been discarded?

I google it there is no information about the label like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishRelease>true</PublishRelease>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Hope to find information like this:`<CheckForDuplicateItems>true</CheckForDuplicateItems>`

Comment: "The" SDK in your case seems to be msbuild, as a csproj-file essentially is an msbuild-script. However I don't understand what you want to achieve here. What has `CheckForDuplicateItems` to do with `PropertyGroup`? Can you share some sample project-file that you're talking about and what you're trying to do with that file?